# Eclipse calls sqlsever stored procedure prompt cannot find stored procedure

Tags: java, sql-server, eclipse, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I've created a new stored procedure on sqlserver that could run on the profiler, but when I call the stored procedure with eclipse, the prompt cannot find the stored procedure. I would appreciate it if you could give me a little help
public class TestID {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    DBUtil db = new DBUtil();
    Connection conn = null;
    CallableStatement  cstmt =null;
    try{
        conn = db.getConnection();
        cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call  dbo.GetSeqVal(?)}");
        cstmt.registerOutParameter(1, java.sql.Types.INTEGER);
        cstmt.execute();
        int count=cstmt.getInt(1);
        System.out.println(count);
    }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            db.closeAll();
        }
}
```

The following is the stored procedure I created in sqlserver,and the invoked statememt

```
USE [test]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
ALTER procedure [dbo].[SP_GetSeqVal]
@result int output
as
begin
    declare @NewSeqValue int

    set NOCOUNT ON

    insert into SEQ_SERIAL_NO(seqval) values ('a')

    set @NewSeqValue = scope_identity()

    set @NewSeqValue = Convert(char(4),Getdate(),112) + right('000000'+CAST(scope_identity() AS varchar(5)),5)

    delete from SEQ_SERIAL_NO WITH (READPAST)

    set @result=@NewSeqValue
    return @NewSeqValue  
end

Declare @NewSeqVal int,@myResult   int
Exec @NewSeqVal=GetSeqVal @myResult output
Print @myResult
print @NewSeqVal
```

the result will appear after the call,What if eclipse calls sqlsever stored procedure tips fail to find stored procedure

Comment: Is there an error message?

Comment: sidenote: you assign a value to `NewSeqValue` 2 times just after each other, that makes no sense to me

Comment: Slight detour...https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix

Comment: the error message is that "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: cannot find the stored procedure. 'dbo.GetSeqVal'。"

Comment: The first time I assigned a value to it was to make the NewSqlValue the last identity value of the table, and the second time to make it output in a particular format. I can run on sqlserver. Can you see why I can't find the stored procedure? Thank you for your answer

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't reply to you immediately yesterday. Could you please check my comments? I really don't know what to do@nitind